# Given the sets $X$ and $Y$ in the real numbers with least upper bounds $a$ and $b$ respectively, prove that $a+b$ is the least upper bound for $X + Y$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I've seen this proof done other ways and I wonder if my way is right. It's very similar to the $\epsilon > 0$ approach I've seen elsewhere but uses a contradiction:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets of real numbers with least upper bounds $a$ and $b$, respectively. To prove that $a+b=\sup{X+Y}$, we need to show (i) that $a+b$ is an upper bound for $X+Y$ and (ii) that $a+b \leq c$ $\forall c \in C$ where $C$ is the set of all upper bounds of $a+b$.

Prove (i): Notice we have $x \leq a$ and $y \leq b$. This means that $x + y \leq a + b$. Thus $a + b$ is an upper bound for $X+Y$.

Prove (ii): Define $p = \sup{X+Y}$. If $a+b \neq \sup{X+Y}$, then $a+b>p$ and $a+b-p>0$. By the supremum property of $X$ and $Y$, we can then find $x_0,y_0$ such that
\begin{align*}
a &< x_0 + \frac{a+b-p}{2} & \text{and} \\
b &< y_0 + \frac{a+b-p}{2}
\end{align*}
Adding inequalities and rearranging terms gives
\begin{align*}
a + b &< x_0 + y_0 + a + b - p \\
p &< x_0 + y_0
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction since $p=\sup{X+Y} \implies p \geq x_0 + y_0$. Thus, $a+b = \sup{X+Y}$.

Comment: For your two inequalities, I think you mean $\sup X < x_0 + \frac{a + b - p}{2}$.

Comment: No, I meant it as written, although I forgot to add that $a$ and $b$ are least upper bounds -- I've edited to reflect this. Now it is equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: Looks good to me.